# Triggering a PowerAutomate desktop flow, using apis, fails due to access issues

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, power-automate, dynamics-365, azure-app-registration

I'm using PowerAutomate, and I'm following this [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/developer/desktop-flow-public-apis) to trigger a desktop flow run using web apis, I can successfully run most GET calls in the guide, but when I trigger a desktop flow run, I get this error:

{\"error\":{\"code\":\"DesktopFlowsConnectionAccessFailedForDesktopFlowConnector\",\"message\":\"User with object identifier 'xxxx' does not have access to the connection 'yyyy' for the Desktop Flows connector.\"}

I couldn't figure out how to solve this issue, or establish this access.

Comment: Could you include more details like how you are generating the bearer token?

Comment: @Sridevi I'm generating the bearer token this way:
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantID>/oauth2/token

grant_type:client_credentials
client_id:<appID>
client_secret:<secret>
resource: https://orgxxxxxx.crm.dynamics.com

Comment: What API permissions you granted for the application?

Comment: Dynamic CRM / user_impersonation -
Microsoft Graph / user.read -
Power Automate / User, Flows.Manage.All, Flows.Read.All, Flows.Read.Plans,Flows.Write.Plans

Comment: Could you try getting token using username password flow instead of client credentials?

Comment: Update: yes, it worked after following your suggestion, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> To resolve the error, try generating access token using **delegated**
> flows like username password flow, authorization code flow or
> interactive flows.

I registered one Azure AD application and added same **API permissions** as below:

[image]

In my case, I used username password flow to generate **access token** via Postman with below parameters:

```http
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantId/oauth2/token
grant_type:password
client_id:appId
client_secret:secret
resource: https://orga9xxxxx.crm.dynamics.com/
username: admin@xxxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com
password:xxxxxxxx
```

**Response:**

[image]

You can decode the above access token in [jwt.ms](https://jwt.ms) website to check **`aud`** and **`scp`** claims like this:

[image]

Now, you can use this **access token** generated by username password flow to trigger a desktop flow.